# How to make purchasing one in-app product several times possible?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm trying to implement in-app billing system in my app to serve ads free version to users. I learned [these steps](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/play-billing-codelab/#0) and finally I succeeded to buy my product by using my test account. (I got the OK `resposeCode` through `onPurchasesUpdated()` method.)

However I could not buy it again. There was no response after calling `launchBillingFlow()`. I don't know why. Even if my product is ads free version (I mean permanent item.), I want to know that buying one item several times. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once a managed product is purchased, it is considered to be "owned".
>   Managed products in the "owned" state cannot be purchased from Google
>   Play. You must send a consumption request for the "owned" managed
>   product before Google Play makes it available for purchase again.
>   Consuming the managed product reverts it to the "unowned" state, and
>   discards the previous purchase data

As soon as the User buys a product from your application, just consume it and keep track of the purchase some other way. By storing the credits on your server may be.

More on the [developer site](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consume)

Answer (score 0):

Just be sure to call `mBillingClient.endConnection()` before calling `mBillingClient.startConnection()` again.

If you don't call `endConnection()` `onPurchaseUpdated()` will be called for every connection that is not closed.

In my case I call `mBillingClient.endConnection()` inside `onDestroy()` method of my activity.